# Checkbox not in same range in linear layout with programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem in creating programmatically layout in Android. Where I want to display in list with name with check box but check box little down and not in same horizontal range. Here is the my code:

```
mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.exmple);
    mDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mDialog.setTitle("Hobbies");
    mDialog.show();

    final LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) mDialog
            .findViewById(R.id.linear);


    mLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    final Button okButton = new Button(this);

    final int size = hobbyList.size();

    LinearLayout[] mLinearLayout2 = new LinearLayout[size];
    LinearLayout[] mLinearLayout3 = new LinearLayout[size];

    Check = new CheckBox[size];
    Text = new TextView[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        Check[i] = new CheckBox(this);
        Text[i] = new TextView(this);
        mLinearLayout2[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
        mLinearLayout3[i] = new LinearLayout(this);

        Check[i].setId(i);

        Text[i].setText(hobbyList.get(i));

        Text[i].setTypeface(font_regular);
        Text[i].setTextColor(color.black);

        mLinearLayout2[i].addView(Text[i]);
        mLinearLayout3[i].addView(Check[i]);
        mLinearLayout2[i].setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        mLinearLayout3[i].setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

        mLinearLayout.addView(mLinearLayout2[i]);
        mLinearLayout.addView(mLinearLayout3[i]);
                }

    okButton.setText("OK");
    mLinearLayout.addView(okButton);
```

**Here is the output pictures:**

[image]

Comment: You can use table layout for this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the layout
mLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

so the layouts are coming one after another so the checkbox is not in line

you can try having a one relative layout and placing the text and checkbox right and left it's far more easier than your current approach